# Can I install macOS High Sierra on a Macbook pro that runs Big Sur?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, big-sur

Can I install macOS High Sierra on a Macbook pro that runs Big Sur without damaging anything? If so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Which model of MBP? You can‘t downgrade beyond the year the MBP was build.

Comment: What do you mean by "damaging anything?" Installing macOS on a Mac won't damage the Mac, and generally won't damage any software, but if you change macOS versions some software might stop working because it is not compatible with the newly installed version of macOS. It might be helpful if you indicate what you are trying to accomplish by installing High Sierra.

Comment: Your device must be at least a mid 2010 device to be compatible with High Sierra.
I'm not sure what you mean by 'damaging anything', do you mean damaging the hardware or lose all of your data?